# Update view in SwiftUI using nested models

Tags: swift, data-binding, swiftui

I'm trying to create a basic tic-tac-toe game as a practice but I'm not able to update my views according to the model (A nested model) that stores the game state, My code is like the following:

TicTacToeModel stores an Array of SquareModel and SquareModel stores the state like empty, cross or naught.

So I want to update my model each time the user press on an empty square and update my view using this model drawing an "x" or "o"

Models:

```
final class TicTacToeModel: ObservableObject{

    @Published var board = [SquareModel]()
    @Published var activePlayer = Player.x

    init(rowSize: Int) {
        self.rowSize = rowSize
        for _ in (0 ..< self.rowSize * self.rowSize){
            board.append(SquareModel(status: .empty))
        }
    }
}
```

```
class SquareModel: ObservableObject{
     @Published var status: Player = .empty

    init(status: Player) {
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

View:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var boardModel = TicTacToeModel(rowSize: Definitions().lines)

    func getIndex(row:Int, col:Int)-> Int{
        return row * Definitions().lines + col
    }

    func squareAction(index:Int){
        self.boardModel.makeMove(index: index, player: self.boardModel.activePlayer)
    }
    var body: some View {

         VStack {
            Spacer()
            TitleView()
            ZStack{
                BoardView()
                VStack{
                    ForEach(0..<Definitions().lines) { row in
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(0..<Definitions().lines) { col in
                                ZStack{
                                    SquareView (source: self.$boardModel.board[self.getIndex(row: row, col: col)]){
                                        let index = self.getIndex(row: row, col: col)
                                        self.squareAction(index: index)
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .padding(20)
            }
            CurrentPlayerView(currentPlayer: self.boardModel.activePlayer)
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.boardModel.resetGame()
            }) {
                Text("Restart game!")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
            }
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.horizontal)

    }
}
```

```
struct SquareView: View {
    @Binding var source: SquareModel
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        xoImageView(player: source.status)
            .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded({ () in
            self.action()
        }))
    }
}
```

Note: The model is working fine and store correctly all the properties

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableObject/ObservedObject` is tuned to be a one level ViewModel bridge in MVVM, where model is assumed to be value. So hierarchical updates within `ObservableObject` are not supported *automatically*.

So, considering `TicTacToeModel` as a ViewModel part, the simplest approach, and preferable, would be to change model, which is `SquareModel`, from `class` to `struct` as below

```
struct SquareModel {
    var status: Player = .empty
}
```

as a result any changes in `SquareModel` will update `board` property in `TicTacToeModel` that updates view.